# How to use a dynamically evaluated angulajs class and append it to the div?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, pug

I currently have this (in jade)

```
div(ng-class = "{'{{cardselector.products[0].imageCarousel}}':
                        cardselector.products[0].imageCarousel != null}")
```

When the page loads and the `imageCarousel` object is updated and then I expect it to add the class evaluated to the `div` but that's not happening. It's only evaluating the `class` but not adding it to the `div`.

Could anyone help?

Comment: How about this: `div.ng-class="[cardselector.products[0].imageCarousel]"`

Comment: @Teh i'll try that out thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following jade (pug) code seems to be working:

```
div(ng-app='')
  div(ng-controller='MyCtrl')
    div(ng-class='[cardselector.products[0].imageCarousel]') Hello!
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxwyKj

Comment: Thank you this resolved my issue i added the condition in an ng-if `(ng-if='cardselector.products[0].imageCarousel != null',ng-class='[cardselector.products[0].imageCarousel]')`

Answer (score 2):

With my understanding of Pug, what you're doing is setting the class on your div to `ng-class`, what you want is to set the attribute `ng-class` to your value.

This could be accomplished by the following:

```
div(ng-class="{'{{cardselector.products[0].imageCarousel}}': cardselector.products[0].imageCarousel != null}")
```

To set the class to the value of the variable

```
div(ng-class="cardselector.products[0].imageCarousel")
```

I used Teh's plunkr to show what I mean.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xLEobm

**Note:** I'm still unsure of when you're compiling through angular, so it still might not render if your template is interpreted after angular compiles.

Comment: Thank you , i missed adding the brackets in my initial question , i'm compiling using spring java plugin , but the issue is with angularjs and how it interprets this code ? after this is evaluated `{{cardselector.products[0].imageCarousel}}` the value generated is not added to the class ? would you be able to help me resolve that

Comment: You cannot use interpolation for the name of the class in an `ngClass` directive.  You should be able to do the following: `{cardsleector.products[0].imageCarousel:carselector.products[0].imageCarousel != null}`

Comment: i have a dynamic class name value that i need to add to this div depending on whether a value is available ,do you have any suggestion on how i can resolve this .Thank you

Comment: just tried this and i'm getting syntax errors raised by pug `ng-class="{cardselector.products[0].imageCarousel:cardselector.products[0].imageCarousel != null}"`

Comment: Yeah sorry, if you just want to set the class to what the value is, then check my edited answer

Comment: you were right interpolation prevented the evaluated class from being assigned to the ng-class value this was my final soln `(ng-if='cardselector.products[0].imageCarousel != null',ng-class='[cardselector.products[0].imageCarousel]')`

Comment: The ng-if is not necessary.  Since the result will be null, there simply won't be a class applied.